# What does '?' after href do?

Tags: html, http

What does ? after href do?  Often time you will see something like this

```
href='?page=1'
```

Does anybody knows? Thanks in advance to all for the help.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't href='?page=#', ie. with quotes around it and a value?  Then it would be a link to the current page with a query-string parameter

Comment: yes I edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means it is a link to the current webpage with a query-string parameter.  In this case the page number.  This is usually if you have a dynamic page listing contents and limiting the number per page.

Comment: so page variable is passed to the current webpage in this case?

Comment: @Bootstrap4 yes

Answer (score 3):

The "?" mark is very useful and important in many ways. for example, and uses to identify a particular usage for specific reasons, one of these reason is that when you have a website with three languages exists but it has the same pages. check the following links below.

```
http://example.com/news?language=EN
```

The language of example website is in English

```
http://example.com/news?language=RU
```

The language of example website is in Russian

```
http://example.com/news?language=DE
```

The language of example website is in Germany

Other reason is when you have a dynamic page that contains only one page with many contents thats stored in website's database. before it was static pages like the following links below

```
http://example.com/page1.html
http://example.com/page2.html
http://example.com/page3.html
```

As you can see we have three pages. how about that we can have many pages but in the same one page. the only thing is different is to change the parameter of the page itself.

Let's say you own an e-library. you don't waste your life creating thousands of pages working on book details, you can simply create a book page with isbn parameter as it shown below

```
 https://example.com/books?isbn=0132947048
```

It also used to track online campaigns and identify which source that users coming from...

```
http://example.com/?source=StackOverFlow&medium=Banner
```

Hope I answered your question clearly :)